# How to read string and get the value from stringlist in DELPHI

Tags: parsing, delphi

how to read a string and then get a String as value from a file.
then i need to show that value/string into a TextEdit component.

> example:
>
> BHG|22|CLASS|12345^JOHN CARTER||200|Good|155^200|
>
> BHG|333|CLASS|23231^AMIRA||100|BAD|100^150|

i need to get string  "200" in TextEdit1 based on '22' value
and then get string  "100" in TextEdit2 based on '333' value.

Comment: Split the string. Populate a dictionary. Look up the values in the dictionary. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Delimiter` and `DelimitedText` of a `TStringList` to do this in a few lines
of code - see below.

Briefly, a TStringList is like an array of strings that you
can reference by index.  You can get it to parse an input string into the array
by setting the value of the delimiter, in your case '|' and then assigning the
input string to its DelimitedText property.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringList : TStringList;
begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    StringList.Delimiter := '|';
    StringList.DelimitedText := 'BHG|22|CLASS|12345^JOHN CARTER||200|Good|155^200|';
    Edit1.Text := StringList[6];    //  Fills Edit1.Text with 200
  finally
    StringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you believe the question to be "how do I split a string", surely you should close the question as a duplicate of one of the many pre-existing questions that ask that? FWIW, I would close for another reason, because I think that the user is asking multiple questions here. Yes there is splitting, but there is also lookup of key/value pairs.

Comment: @MartynA - I would suggest adding `StringList.StrictDelimiter := True;` and pulling from `StringList[5]` . The space in JOHN CARTER is being treated as a delimiter without StrictDelimiter set to True. If you use the other example string shown in the question, the value in StringList[6] would not be 100.

Comment: @Dale:  Good point, thanks. I rolled my example using D7.  I'll re-do it in 10.2 later.

Comment: @David, so as the recent one about freeing arrays (that you've answered many times before). But there's a lot more. Though I don't want any arguments.. Personally, if I find a question that can be actually answered by reading a manual, I just drop a comment. It's better as the OP can freely delete the question (I think that with an answer cannot).

Comment: @Victoria True. I had trouble finding a good dupe candidate for that memory leak question though.

Answer (score -1):

While *MartynA's* answer uses `TStringList` to split a string into separate words (nice trick, I should notice), I implemented another way to do the same task. See the code below.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S, D, Res: String;
  Arr: Array of String;
  i: integer;
begin
  S := 'BHG|22|CLASS|12345^JOHN CARTER||200|Good|155^200|';
  D := '|';

  Res := '';
  for i:=Low(S) to High(S) do
    begin
      if S[i] <> D then
        Res := Res + S[i]
      else
        begin
          SetLength(Arr, Length(Arr) + 1);
          Arr[Length(Arr) - 1] := Res;
          Res := '';
        end;
    end;

  // Display each word to us
  for i:=Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    ShowMessage(Arr[i]);
end;
```

Well, now all what you have to do is to build your condition to get appropriate value from array by iterating its each entry and comparing returned value with needed one.

Comment: There are tens of questions asking how to split strings already on SO. Surely we don't need yet more string spltting answers? Or if we do, how about adding your answer to an existing question that more directly asks about splitting? Because this question asks about more than just splitting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I agree with you. When there are lots of the same questions and answer it leads to a big problem. I have to admit this question is too broad to be only about splitting a string. What about to add my answer to the question: I think it is not a good idea, since all my formatting and title reforming improvements in question (not the present one) were rejected. Are you a moderator? If you think it is will be helpful then I ask you to add my answer to the question. Otherwise I should delete my answer as unuseful.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, what if I rewrite my answer to not only split the string but also search a needed value as in the last part of question? Or this question will be closed anyway?

Comment: @TomBrunberg alright. I just have some free time and wanted to be helpful to others... But not  today). Yeap, `TListView` problem was interested enough.